# PrimeNG Dropdown Data is Not Being Displayed with Translate

Tags: angular, angular5, dropdown, primeng

I am trying to display translated list in PrimeNG dropdown.

HTML :

```
<p-dropdown [options]="companyProfileCategories" [(ngModel)]="CompanyCategoryId" [style]="{'width':'150px'}">
    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="position: relative;height: 25px;">
            <div style="font-size:14px;margin-top:4px;color:white;">{{car.Name|json}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

This is getting me data in console element like following :

[image: Console Element Output]

But the dropdown is still not displayed. Check Image.

[image: Empty Dropdown]

I have tried changing CSS and other styles.

Array Data :

```
companyProfileCategories = [{
    "ID": "SomeID",
    "Name": "ad_media"
}, {
    "ID": "SomeID2",
    "Name": "photos"
}]
```

Comment: Please click all the tags, read there info, do you actually use them all? I doubt you do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown), the `[options]` array should be a `SelectItem` array, so it must have two required fields that are `label` and `value`, where `value` is the value of the dropdown and `label` is the displayed string. Your array should be like:

```
companyProfileCategories = [{
    "value": "SomeID",
    "label": "ad_media"
}, {
    "value": "SomeID2",
    "label": "photos"
}]
```